# Prompt user for sound permission

Tags: javascript, audio, prompt

Is this even a thing?

Okay I have a quick intro, the intro shows a logo and plays a sound according to the animation, is unskippable and doesn't take more than 4 seconds

The problem is, if the users don't give the permission the audio will be handled automatically and this will prevent to actually play the sound or **delay it** if the user don't interact with it or *does it late* in future visits

This seems to happen on Chrome

How can I promt the user about sound permission needs to be handled by him, asking to grant permission if he wants?

Or is there a way to keep playing the sound even if the sound is in "auto", meaning haven't been interacted with by the user yet?

Or how I can anyway play the sound silently on background and, when the user interacts with it, raise the volume so the sound sounds perfectly timed and not delayed?

Or what is the best approach i must take that will be much appreciated?

I've already tried a bunch of things that doesn't seem to effect a ****, like using Howler audio library (amazing by the way) searching for an unexisting answer and many other things in vain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone who ever will be stuck on here check this:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

I was able to check the `AudioContext` `State` and then if `suspended`, set an `interval` counting each millisecond, if the user, meanwhile the sound "that must be playing" interacts with the page, this sound will be resumed on that lovely position mantaining the freaking desired and badly needed timing

Then a button suggest the user to go ahead and feel touchy

Using howler you can check the `AudioContext` `State` easily with

```
Howler.ctx.state
```